# Specialization of polymorphic functions

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, ghc, typeclass

In his talk “Classes, Jim, but not as we know them” Simon Peyton-Jones talks about how type classes are implemented in GHC by having polymorphic functions taking an extra parameter that is a dictionary with the correct functions for the type(s) given to the function.

He then said that GHC often optimizes functions by special-casing functions and not actually passing this dictionary at runtime. He then said that this is not always possible because *Haskell has polymorphic recursion, so even if you have the whole program, you cannot necessarily eliminate all polymorphism.*

What did he mean by this? What is an example of a program where one cannot know the types a polymorphic function will be passed at compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a typical example of polymorphic recursion. Let's say we have a data type similar to a list, but each element has a type twice as "big" as the previous one:

```
data Poly a = Nil | Cons a (Poly (a,a)) deriving Show

foo :: Poly Int
foo = Cons 3 (Cons (4,5) (Cons ((6,7),(8,9)) Nil))

length' :: Poly a -> Int
length' Nil = 0
length' (Cons _ xs) = 1 + length' xs
```

Notice that the recursive call to `length'` has a different type from the original call.

Since it's impossible to know statically which such lists might be created, we can't eliminate all dictionaries from the program.

Comment: So it's the *data type* that is recursive when talking about *polymorphic recursion* in this case?

Comment: @beta: No, polymorphic recursion happens when you recursively call the function on types different from what you started with. `f :: Show a => Int -> a -> String; f 0 x = show x; f n x = f (n - 1) [x]` is a polymorphic recursion happening on ordinary lists.

Comment: Whoops ... actually added a polymorphic recursive function to the example.

Comment: It *does* make sense why these examples would need the dictionary at runtime. Thanks! (I actually had no idea that functions like these were allowed by the type system at all.)

Comment: They are only allowed if you give a type signature.  Inference is undecidable for polymorphic recursion.